# new command within table parameters

Tags: tables, macros, environments, longtable

I used \newcommand to define a variable and I used that variable in one of the table parameters but that produced an error

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,english]{report}

\usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text- not needed for a longtable

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[1]

\newcommand{\SecondCol}{p{0.175\linewidth}}

\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{EFEFEF}

\begin{longtable}{|>{\columncolor{lightgray}} p{0.2\linewidth} | \SecondCol | p{0.175\linewidth} |}
\noalign{\nobreak\vskip-.5pt} \hline\noalign{\nobreak\vskip.5pt}  
Here & Here & Here
\\[.5pt]\noalign{\nobreak\vskip-.5pt} \hline\noalign{\nobreak\vskip.5pt} 
\endfirsthead
\noalign{\nobreak\vskip-.5pt} \hline\noalign{\nobreak\vskip.5pt}  
Here & Here & Here
\\[.5pt]\noalign{\nobreak\vskip-.5pt} \hline\noalign{\nobreak\vskip.5pt} 
\endhead
\noalign{\nobreak\vskip-.5pt} \hline\noalign{\nobreak\vskip.5pt} 
\endfoot
foo & bar & dada \\[.5pt]\noalign{\nobreak\vskip-.5pt} \hline\noalign{\nobreak\vskip.5pt}
foo & bar & dada \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar & dada \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar & dada \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar & dada \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar & dada \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar & dada \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar & dada \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar & dada \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar & dada \\ \cline{2-2}
foo & bar & dada \\[.5pt]\noalign{\nobreak\vskip-.5pt} \hline\noalign{\nobreak\vskip.5pt}
\caption{Your caption here} % needs to go inside longtable environment
\label{tab:myfirstlongtable}
\end{longtable} 
\end{document}
```

the problem is with \SeconCol variable. Any help ?

Comment: You could use `\newcolumntype{T}{p{0.175\linewidth}}` instead of `\newcommand{\SecondCol}{p{0.175\linewidth}}` in the preamble and `T` instead of `\SecondCol` inside of the table.

Comment: Thanks. It worked!

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: What's with the `\noalign{\nobreak\vskip-.5pt} \hline\noalign{\nobreak\vskip.5pt}` instructions? Specifically, why create a gap (of 0.5pt)  in the vertical lines?

Comment: I'd also replace `>{\columncolor{lightgray}}` with `>{\cellcolor{lightgray}}` as the command really affects just one cell at a time.

Comment: Just in case it isn't yet clear to you: Except for in special column type arguments (like the mandatory width argument to `p`-type columns) macros aren't expanded in the table preamble. Instead each token is interpreted as a string and it is then checked whether a column type of that name is defined (hence `\newcolumntype\SecondCol{<stuff>}` would actually work, but it wouldn't define a `\SecondCol` macro, instead it'd define a column type with the name `\SecondCol`).